# WPF DataGrid TemplateColumn - Scrolling results in strange effects

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a strange effect in my datagrid. In this sample the datagrid has 200 rows and the first column has a incrementing index. The datagrid has a MaxHeight property, so i see after loading only the first 30 rows.

I can scroll down the 200 rows but i never see in the first column the numbers 30-200 only repeatly 0-29!?! (I checked that the collection has the right values)

If I change the columns from DataGridTemplateColumn to DataGridTextColumn, I see all the values but this is not what i want.

**Has someone an idea, why the cell content not show the right value?**

Here is my code. This is a reduced sample of a large MVVM project. Please be lenient of this construction.

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <local:RowCellConverter x:Key="rcconv" />
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BusinessDataGrid}">
        <Grid
            Margin="5"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Background="Transparent"
            Focusable="False"
            Visibility="Visible">
            <DataGrid
                Name="dataGrid"
                Height="700"
                MaxHeight="600"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                CanUserResizeRows="False"
                CanUserSortColumns="False"
                ColumnWidth="*"
                EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
                EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                Initialized="dataGrid_Initialized"
                ItemsSource="{Binding rows}"
                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader">
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyFieldCell" DataType="DataGridTemplateColumn">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Background="LightSalmon">Hallo</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox
                                x:Name="TableCell"
                                DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}, Converter={StaticResource rcconv}}"
                                IsReadOnly="False"
                                Background="{Binding Path=StateColor}"
                                Text="{Binding Path=MyValue}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl Name="iControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainWindow.bFields}" />
</Grid>
```

And the code behind:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<BusinessField> bFields = new ObservableCollection<BusinessField>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        BusinessDataGrid bdg = new BusinessDataGrid();
        foreach (string col in new string[] { "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6", })
        {
            bdg.cols.Add(col);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            FieldRow fr = new FieldRow();
            foreach(string col in bdg.cols)
            {
                FieldCell fc = new FieldCell();
                fc.MyValue = string.Format("{0:000}{1}", i, col);
                fr.cells.Add(fc);
            }
            bdg.rows.Add(fr);
        }
        InitializeComponent();
        ItemsControl ic = iControl;
        ic.ItemsSource = bFields;
        bFields.Add(bdg);
    }

    private void dataGrid_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        if (dg != null)
        {
            BusinessDataGrid bdg = dg.DataContext as BusinessDataGrid;
            if (bdg != null)
                bdg.OnUIInitialized(dg);
        }
    }
}
public class BusinessField : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChangedEvent;
    public void SendPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        VerifyCalledOnUIThread();
        if (propertyChangedEvent != null)
            propertyChangedEvent(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add
        {
            VerifyCalledOnUIThread();
            propertyChangedEvent += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            VerifyCalledOnUIThread();
            propertyChangedEvent -= value;
        }
    }
    [Conditional("Debug")]
    protected void VerifyCalledOnUIThread()
    {
        Debug.Assert(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher == Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher, "Call must be made on UI thread.");
    }
}

public class BusinessDataGrid:BusinessField
{
    public List<string> cols = new List<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<FieldRow> rows = new ObservableCollection<FieldRow>();

    public void OnUIInitialized(DataGrid datagrid)
    {
        DataTemplate dt = (DataTemplate)datagrid.Resources["MyFieldCell"];
        datagrid.Columns.Clear();
        foreach(string col in cols)
        {
            DataGridTemplateColumn dgtc = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
            {
                CellTemplate = dt,
                Visibility = Visibility.Visible,
                Header = col,
                SortMemberPath=col,
            };
            datagrid.Columns.Add(dgtc);
        }
        datagrid.ItemsSource = rows;
    }

}

public class RowCellConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = value as DataGridCell;

        if((string)parameter == "FieldCell")
        {

        }
        if (cell == null)
            return null;
        DataGridCellsPresenter dgcp = TreeHelper.GetVisualParent<DataGridCellsPresenter>(cell);

        int ci = dgcp.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(cell);
        FieldRow fr = cell.DataContext as FieldRow;
        if (fr == null)
            return null;

        object ret = null;
        switch((string)parameter)
        {
            case "StateColor":
                ret = fr.cells[ci].StateColor;
                break;
            case "MyValue":
                ret = fr.cells[ci].MyValue;
                break;
            default:
                ret = fr.cells[ci];
                break;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class TreeHelper
{
    #endregion
    public static T GetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
                return (T)child;
            else
            {
                T childOfChild = GetVisualChild<T>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static T GetVisualParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        //get parent item
        DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);    //we’ve reached the end of the tree
        if (parentObject == null) return null;

        //check if the parent matches the type we’re looking for
        T parent = parentObject as T;
        if (parent != null)
            return parent;
        else
            return GetVisualParent<T>(parentObject);
    }
}
public enum FieldCellState
{
    Ok,
    Error
}

public class FieldRow
{
    public ObservableCollection<FieldCell> cells = new ObservableCollection<FieldCell>();
}
public class FieldCell : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Colname;
    private string myValue;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return MyValue;
    }

    public string MyValue
    {
        get { return myValue; }
        set { myValue = value; }
    }
    public FieldCellState MyState
    {
        get { return (MyValue.Contains("7")) ? FieldCellState.Error : FieldCellState.Ok; }
    }
    public Brush StateColor
    {
        get { return (MyState == FieldCellState.Ok) ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightSalmon); }
    }
    private PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChangedEvent;
    public void SendPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        VerifyCalledOnUIThread();
        if (propertyChangedEvent != null)
            propertyChangedEvent(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add
        {
            VerifyCalledOnUIThread();
            propertyChangedEvent += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            VerifyCalledOnUIThread();
            propertyChangedEvent -= value;
        }
    }
    [Conditional("Debug")]
    protected void VerifyCalledOnUIThread()
    {
        Debug.Assert(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher == Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher, "Call must be made on UI thread.");
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use the DataGridTextColumn I see in the debugger, that after scrolling the binding is called for all visible rows but if I use the DataGridTemplateColumn this doesn't occur.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have these two options enabled

```
EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
EnableRowVirtualization="True"
```

It try to virtualize it for you. Try to make them False and see if you can see your content correctly. Keep in mind setting them to false it will make your `DataGrid` to load much slower.

Try to do this for each column instead of making a template at resource level. This is just an example you can adapt it to your style.

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Some Name" IsReadOnly="False" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RichTextBox>
                                <FlowDocument IsOptimalParagraphEnabled="True" IsHyphenationEnabled="True">
                                    <Paragraph FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="14">
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=First ,Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=FirstText ,Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=SearchedText ,Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="#FFE34C"/>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=SecondText ,Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </FlowDocument>
                            </RichTextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: column virtualization wont have any affect on this as it is the rows that are missing count.

Comment: I need the virtualization because the 200 rows are only in the sample. There can be much more. With 2000 rows the loading time is > 10s.

Comment: @Terkosh I gave you and example for my case which works fine. Take a look at it and let me know if you need any help.

Comment: @Lion King thank you for your answer. A very interesting text construct but it is the same effect. If i use a DataGridTextColumn, i get for all visible cells a property-get access and if i use the DataGridTemplateColumn only one time at loading and not after scrolling.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you are using a third party grid ? issue is with how it is virtualized

i had this issue once and the reason was I was using an Identity column of the grid and hence the column was auto-generated.

the grid is being virtualized and hence cant calculate no of rows above or below the view.

you can either stop virtualization if you don't need it (200 rows or so wont make any difference)

or add a new column that is bound to index of item in the collection, that should work

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using a standard datagrid from .net 4.5.2. I need the virtualization because the 200 rows are only in the sample. There can be much more. Your other suggestion with the new column, I don't understand really.